# int24 - 24 bit integral datatype

Tags: c++

Is there a 24Bit primitive integral datatype in C++?

If there is none, would it be possible to create a class int24 (, uint24 ) ?

Its purpose could be:

- manipulating soundfiles in 24 bit format
- manipulating bitmapdata without alphachannel

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wrote this to help me with audio manipulation.  Its not the fastest but it works for me :)

```
const int INT24_MAX = 8388607;

class Int24
{
protected:
    unsigned char m_Internal[3];
public:
    Int24()
    {
    }

    Int24( const int val )
    {
        *this   = val;
    }

    Int24( const Int24& val )
    {
        *this   = val;
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        if ( m_Internal[2] & 0x80 ) // Is this a negative?  Then we need to siingn extend.
        {
            return (0xff << 24) | (m_Internal[2] << 16) | (m_Internal[1] << 8) | (m_Internal[0] << 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return (m_Internal[2] << 16) | (m_Internal[1] << 8) | (m_Internal[0] << 0);
        }
    }

    operator float() const
    {
        return (float)this->operator int();
    }

    Int24& operator =( const Int24& input )
    {
        m_Internal[0]   = input.m_Internal[0];
        m_Internal[1]   = input.m_Internal[1];
        m_Internal[2]   = input.m_Internal[2];

        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator =( const int input )
    {
        m_Internal[0]   = ((unsigned char*)&input)[0];
        m_Internal[1]   = ((unsigned char*)&input)[1];
        m_Internal[2]   = ((unsigned char*)&input)[2];

        return *this;
    }

    /***********************************************/

    Int24 operator +( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this + (int)val );
    }

    Int24 operator -( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this - (int)val );
    }

    Int24 operator *( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this * (int)val );
    }

    Int24 operator /( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this / (int)val );
    }

    /***********************************************/

    Int24 operator +( const int val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this + val );
    }

    Int24 operator -( const int val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this - val );
    }

    Int24 operator *( const int val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this * val );
    }

    Int24 operator /( const int val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this / val );
    }

    /***********************************************/
    /***********************************************/


    Int24& operator +=( const Int24& val )
    {
        *this   = *this + val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator -=( const Int24& val )
    {
        *this   = *this - val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator *=( const Int24& val )
    {
        *this   = *this * val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator /=( const Int24& val )
    {
        *this   = *this / val;
        return *this;
    }

    /***********************************************/

    Int24& operator +=( const int val )
    {
        *this   = *this + val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator -=( const int val )
    {
        *this   = *this - val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator *=( const int val )
    {
        *this   = *this * val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator /=( const int val )
    {
        *this   = *this / val;
        return *this;
    }

    /***********************************************/
    /***********************************************/

    Int24 operator >>( const int val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this >> val );
    }

    Int24 operator <<( const int val ) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this << val );
    }

    /***********************************************/

    Int24& operator >>=( const int val )
    {
        *this = *this >> val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator <<=( const int val )
    {
        *this = *this << val;
        return *this;
    }

    /***********************************************/
    /***********************************************/

    operator bool() const
    {
        return (int)*this != 0;
    }

    bool operator !() const
    {
        return !((int)*this);
    }

    Int24 operator -()
    {
        return Int24( -(int)*this );
    }

    /***********************************************/
    /***********************************************/

    bool operator ==( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this == (int)val;
    }

    bool operator !=( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this != (int)val;
    }

    bool operator >=( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this >= (int)val;
    }

    bool operator <=( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this <= (int)val;
    }

    bool operator >( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this > (int)val;
    }

    bool operator <( const Int24& val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this < (int)val;
    }

    /***********************************************/

    bool operator ==( const int val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this == val;
    }

    bool operator !=( const int val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this != val;
    }

    bool operator >=( const int val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this >= val;
    }

    bool operator <=( const int val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this <= val;
    }

    bool operator >( const int val ) const
    {
        return ((int)*this) > val;
    }

    bool operator <( const int val ) const
    {
        return (int)*this < val;
    }

    /***********************************************/
    /***********************************************/
};
```

Comment: this looks very nice, thanks.
you have also bit shifting operators, great stuff!
1 question: how to use the class to store the data in a, or to read from a stream? would it be possible to use the << and >> operator too?

Comment: @Oops: I think not, since there are two possible implicit casts of Int24 - to int and to float, and the compiler has no way of choosing which cast to perform, and then use the result with `ostream::operator<<`. But you can easily add operators << and >> for ostreams and istreams yourself...

Comment: As conio says if you want stream support you'll need to add the implementations yourself.  Its not particularly difficult though :)

Comment: could you please give a short example how this must look like? thanks

Comment: (not the down voter) How does this handle endian issues, if at all?  Probably not a big deal, but it popped into my head.  The other thing I see is type_casts to (int) in the comparisons and elsewhere may fail when this is placed into an array due to alignment issues.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Yeah it is designed for little endian but thats pretty much standard in the wave files I use it with.  I'm pretty sure those casts won't fail though because of alignment or otherwise ... Check out my operator int() implementation :)

Comment: Ah, missed that.  Well then, carry on!

Comment: Most of the operators here are unnecessary.  Removing some of them makes more code "just magically work".  Also, the the endian bias removed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54aa37188d37a23d  (

Comment: @MooingDuck: Why does "int24(INT24_MIN-1)" equal -1?  It ought to be undefined behaviour but thats still very strange behaviour ... (No idea what my original code would have done there mind)

Comment: @Goz: I'd put in special logic that if the 32bit value is negative, then the stored 24bit value is also negative, always.  `INT24_MIN` is 0xff800000.  Ergo, `INT24_MIN-1` is `0xff7fffff`, which is stored as `0x7fffff`, _and then the "negative" bit is set_.  Then it's `-xFFFFFF`, which is -1.  Since I didn't do that for positives, and it's counterintuitive, I've removed it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eac40bbbb3898348

Comment: @MooingDuck, there is some bug in your code. `int24 a=40; ++a; --a; cout << a << endl;` yields 42. `operator--` shouldn't add 1.

Comment: @exore trivially fixed though. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92bfe26a45ea03a5

Comment: @MooingDuck, hum... `int24 a=40; ++a; --a; cout << a << endl;` still yields 42. You only fixed `a--` but forgot `--a`.

Answer (score 23):

Depending on the requirements I'd use a bitfield for it.

```
struct int24{
    unsigned int data : 24;
};
```

Or, if a separation is easier, just use 3 bytes (chars).

Btw, both use cases you mention in the question generally use 32bit integers. In the case of audio processing you'll generally convert to 32 bit ints (or floats, preferably, to prevent overflow situations you'd get with fixed point or integer math) when loading in chunks of audio because you're not going to have the entire file in memory at once.

For image data, people just tend to use 32 bit integers and ignore the alpha 8 alpha bits all together, or if you're dealing with a tightly packed format you're probably better of just manipulating them as char-pointers anyway because you'll have all channels separate. It's going to be a performance/memory trade-off anyway because writing one int is generally faster than three chars separately; however it will take 25% more memory.

Packing structs like this is compiler specific. However, in Visual Studio you'd do the following to make the struct exactly 24 bits.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct int24{
    unsigned int data : 24;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: it would be still padded to 32bits in most cases.

Comment: Most compilers allow you to turn off the padding to enable these tightly packed formats.

Comment: could you explain how to "turn off padding" / "create a packed struct" ? maybe you could modify your code

Comment: @Oops I updated the answer with the correct code sample for Visual Studio, however your compiler might do this differently.

Comment: @JasperBekkers - Need a semi-colon on the second code block's struct. I wouldn't let me edit it since it was < 6 characters.

Comment: While implementation defined, this answer is _far_ faster than the accepted one

Comment: @JasperBekkers Which would make it impossible operate over it with SIMD due to bad alignment, I guess! You'd have to unpack and repack at least, which will be very costly. I'd really rather have my program waste that 1/4 extra memory!

Comment: I got excited by this answer but it doesn't get packed on VS2017.  sizeof(int24) == 4.

Answer (score 8):

Working with anything smaller than an integer (32 or 64 bit depending on your architecture) is not ideal. All CPU operations of the smaller data types (short, etc) are done using integer arithmetic. Conversion to and from the CPU has to be done, slowing your application down (even if it is just a tad).

My advice: Store them as 32 (or 64 bit) integers to improve your overall speed. When it comes time to do I/O, then you'll have to do the conversion yourself.

As far as manipulating audio data, there are many libraries available that take care of the I/O for you - unless you want to start learning how PCM, etc are stored - as well as other DSP functions. I would suggest using one of the many libraries out there.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Not because we have the same name or anything.

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm ten years late, but what do you think about a bitset solution ?

```cpp
class i24
{
    std::bitset<24> m_value;

public:
    constexpr i24(int value) noexcept: m_value {static_cast<unsigned long long>(value)} {}

    operator int() const
    {
        constexpr std::uint32_t negative_mask = (0xff << 24);
        return (m_value[23] ? negative_mask : 0) | m_value.to_ulong();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is creating an Int24 class and use it like primitive types.
It would be like:

Int24.h

---

```
#ifndef INT24_H
#define INT24_H

class Int24
{
public:
    Int24();
    Int24(unsigned long);

    Int24 operator+ (Int24 value);
    Int24 operator* (int value);
    Int24 operator/ (int value);

    void operator= (unsigned long value);
    void operator= (Int24 value);
    operator int() const;


    // Declare prefix and postfix increment operators.
    Int24 &operator++();       // Prefix increment operator.
    Int24 operator++(int);     // Postfix increment operator.

    // Declare prefix and postfix decrement operators.
    Int24 &operator--();       // Prefix decrement operator.
    Int24 operator--(int);     // Postfix decrement operator.

    unsigned long value() const;

private:
    unsigned char mBytes[3] ;
};

#endif // INT24_H
```

---

Int24.cpp

---

```
#include "Int24.h"

Int24::Int24()
{
    mBytes[0] = 0;
    mBytes[1] = 0;
    mBytes[2] = 0;
}

Int24::Int24(unsigned long value)
{
    mBytes[0] = ( value         & 0xff);
    mBytes[1] = ((value >>  8)  & 0xff);
    mBytes[2] = ((value >> 16 ) & 0xff);
}

Int24 Int24::operator+(Int24 value)
{
    Int24 retVal;
    unsigned long myValue;
    unsigned long addValue;

     myValue = this->mBytes[2];
     myValue <<= 8;
     myValue |= this->mBytes[1];
     myValue <<= 8;
     myValue |= this->mBytes[0];

     addValue = value.mBytes[2];
     addValue <<= 8;
     addValue |= value.mBytes[1];
     addValue <<= 8;
     addValue |= value.mBytes[0];

     myValue += addValue;

     retVal = myValue;

     return retVal;
}

Int24 Int24::operator*(int value)
{
    (*this) = (*this).value() * value;
    return (*this);
}

Int24 Int24::operator/(int value)
{
    (*this) = (*this).value() / value;
    return (*this);
}

void Int24::operator=(unsigned long value)
{
    mBytes[0] = ( value         & 0xff);
    mBytes[1] = ((value >>  8)  & 0xff);
    mBytes[2] = ((value >> 16 ) & 0xff);
}

void Int24::operator=(Int24 value)
{
    mBytes[0] = value.mBytes[0];
    mBytes[1] = value.mBytes[1];
    mBytes[2] = value.mBytes[2];
}

Int24 &Int24::operator++()
{
    (*this) = (*this).value() + 1;
    return *this;
}

Int24 Int24::operator++(int)
{
    Int24 temp = (*this);
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
}

Int24 &Int24::operator--()
{
    (*this) = (*this).value() - 1;
    return *this;
}

Int24 Int24::operator--(int)
{
    Int24 temp = (*this);
    --(*this);
    return temp;
}

Int24::operator int() const
{
    return value();
}

unsigned long Int24::value() const
{
    unsigned long retVal;

    retVal = this->mBytes[2];
    retVal <<= 8;
    retVal |= this->mBytes[1];
    retVal <<= 8;
    retVal |= this->mBytes[0];

    return retVal;
}
```

---

You can download the Int24 and Int48 classes from [my GitHub link](https://github.com/EsmaeilChitgar/Int48_Int24).
Also there is an example which shows you how to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, bitfield does not work in some Linux distributions.

Answer (score -2):

No - all you can really do is:

```
typedef int32_t int24_t;
```

which helps to make code/intent more readable/obvious, but doesn't impose any limits on range or storage space.

Comment: thanks for your post. But wouldn't it be very memory comsumable when reading a huge file? because 24bit raw audio is very huge at all.

Comment: @Oops: you probably want to unpack your 24 bit data to 32 bit when yo read it, otherwise you will need to pack/unpack samples on misaligned boundaries on-the-fly. The only reason to keep the data in its packed form would be if you were *really* pushed for memory.

Comment: The best reason for leaving the sounddata packed as it is, is just playing the sound, isn't it?

Comment: @Oops: it depends on what API you are using for sound playback and what formats it supports. If all you want to do is play the sound then keep it packed. If you want to do any processing of the sound data then it's probably going to be easier and more efficient if it's unpacked.

Comment: I think typedefs like that can misdirect someone who will work with your code after you and don't know that int24_t actually is longer than mentioned in its name. So someone can write code which rely rather on type name than its real size: memcpy(dst, int24_array, 24*numElements); (correct variant is memcpy(dst, int24_array, sizeof(int24_t)*numElements); for those who are interested)

Comment: should at least have called it int_least24_t instead of int24_t - this is exactly the kind of stuff the int_leastX types are meant for

Comment: @OlimilOops Note that if you are dealing with huge audio files and worried about excessive RAM usage, a much more effective approach is *not to read in the entire file to memory at once*.  Instead, only read in the small portion of the file you'll need needing to use in the near future; you can always read more from the disk later when you need to.