# How to define 24bit data type in C?

Tags: c

I will have to work a lot with 24-bit audio data. Which is just unsigned int but instead of 32bit, it is 24bit. So what is the easier way to define and work with 24bit data in C?

Comment: You tagged the question with C++ also, but your question is only about C.

Comment: Why can't you work with 32-bit ints and ignore higher-order bits?

Comment: audio data means he probably has a LOT of data, in which case those lost 8 bits would be meaningful.

Comment: What is your point? Are you aiming to overflow integers when they are above 24-bits, or are you aiming to reduce memory usage?

Comment: @hkBattousai I was suggesting he was trying to reduce memory usage.

Comment: If you can use C++, I recommend [this solution][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682725/int24-24-bit-integral-datatype/2682737#2682737

Comment: Several answers provided but none I think constitute _"easier way to define and work with 24-bit data"_.  It will always be easier, and generally  in speed terms more efficient to work in a natural machine word size.  You could (and probably will) pack the cada for communication and storage, but will generally _process_  it as 32bit data.

Answer (score 17):

Depending on the requirements I'd either use a bitfield for it:

```
struct int24{
    unsigned int data : 24;
};
```

Or, if a separation is easier, just use 3 bytes (`unsigned char`s). You can force the struct to be packed if you don't want it to be padded.

[edit: I see the `C++` tag was removed, but I'm leaving it here regardless]
If you're more comfortable with C++, you can use something like the following:

```
const int INT24_MAX = 8388607;

class Int24
{
protected:
    unsigned char value[3];
public:
    Int24(){}

    Int24( const Int24& val )
    {
        *this   = val;
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        /* Sign extend negative quantities */
        if( value[2] & 0x80 ) {
            return (0xff << 24) | (value[2] << 16)
                                | (value[1] <<  8)
                                |  value[0];
        } else {
            return (value[2] << 16)
                 | (value[1] <<  8)
                 |  value[0];
        }
    }

    Int24& operator= (const Int24& input)
    {
        value[0]   = input.value[0];
        value[1]   = input.value[1];
        value[2]   = input.value[2];

        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator= (const int input)
    {
        value[0]   = ((unsigned char*)&input)[0];
        value[1]   = ((unsigned char*)&input)[1];
        value[2]   = ((unsigned char*)&input)[2];

        return *this;
    }

    Int24 operator+ (const Int24& val) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this + (int)val );
    }

    Int24 operator- (const Int24& val) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this - (int)val );
    }

    Int24 operator* (const Int24& val) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this * (int)val );
    }

    Int24 operator/ (const Int24& val) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this / (int)val );
    }

    Int24& operator+= (const Int24& val)
    {
        *this   = *this + val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator-= (const Int24& val)
    {
        *this   = *this - val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator*= (const Int24& val)
    {
        *this   = *this * val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24& operator/= (const Int24& val)
    {
        *this   = *this / val;
        return *this;
    }

    Int24 operator>> (const int val) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this >> val );
    }

    Int24 operator<< (const int val) const
    {
        return Int24( (int)*this << val );
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return (int)*this != 0;
    }

    bool operator! () const
    {
        return !((int)*this);
    }

    Int24 operator- ()
    {
        return Int24( -(int)*this );
    }

    bool operator== (const Int24& val) const
    {
        return (int)*this == (int)val;
    }

    bool operator!= (const Int24& val) const
    {
        return (int)*this != (int)val;
    }

    bool operator>= (const Int24& val) const
    {
        return (int)*this >= (int)val;
    }

    bool operator<= (const Int24& val) const
    {
        return (int)*this <= (int)val;
    }

    /* Define all operations you need below.. */
```

Comment: Doesn't first bitfield solution align up to 32-bits by default on all major compilers, and thus waste a byte (not even sure that packing pragmas will help here)?  The latter class-based solution works though. 

Comment: With the packed pramga it seems fine (tested on gcc 10): struct uint24 { unsigned int data : 24; } __attribute__((__packed__));

Answer (score 5):

The clean and portable way, assuming your samples are little endian and unsigned:

```
static inline uint32_t getsample(uint8_t *buf, size_t pos)
{
    return buf[3*pos] + 256UL*buf[3*pos+1] + 65536UL*buf[3*pos+2];
}

static inline void putsample(uint8_t *buf, size_t pos, uint32_t sample)
{
    buf[3*pos]=sample;
    buf[3*pos+1]=sample/256;
    buf[3*pos+2]=sample/65536;
}
```

Fixing it up to work for signed values it a little more work, especially if you want to keep it portable. Note that performance might be much better if you convert a whole window of samples to a saner format before processing it, then convert back when you're done.

Comment: "portable" - where `unsigned int` is at least 24 bits.

Comment: In real life you might typedef it anyway, since the number 32 is irrelevant to the problem domain. Depends whether you expect users to do anything with it where they need to be constantly reminded of the exact type (as you would with types that might get promoted to `signed int` or something equally insane). In principle what you want is probably `uint24_fast_t`, but I doubt that many (or any) implementations provide it.

Comment: You could use a hideous `#ifdef` cascade for `UINT_FAST24_MAX`, `UINT_FAST25_MAX`, ... up to 32 (the first that's required to exist) to choose the right type for your `typedef`.... ;-)

Comment: I like the sound of "hideous"!

Comment: Wouldn't signedness be as simple as setting/checking the highest bit of the highest byte in the buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Use a data type that's large enough to hold 24 bits of data. That are `int32_t` or `uint32_t` both defined in *stdint.h*

You're working with audio data, so you want addition working (you need it for mixing). Also having some additional 8 bits available is not a bad thing, as it gives you about 24dB of extra dynamic range, which you'll need mixing several sources that make full use of the 24bit dynamic range.

Note that you were just asking about a datatype to use for 24 bit samples. If you're going to read a tighly packed stream of 24bit sample frames, you'll have to split that one up. First you must know if the stream is *big endian* or *low endian*. Then you can use something like this to rearrange the stream into samples:

```
uint32_t bitstream_BE_to_sample(uint8_t bits[3])
{
    return (bits[0] << 16) | (bits[1] << 8) | (bits[2]);
}

uint32_t bitstream_LE_to_sample(uint8_t bits[3])
{
    return (bits[2] << 16) | (bits[1] << 8) | (bits[0]);
}

uint8_t *bitstream;
uint32_t *samples;
for(;;) {
    *samples = bitstream_XX_to_sample(bitstream);
    samples++;
    bistream += 3;

    if(end_of_bitstream())
         break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but none of the answers are very suboptimal for audio work - not to say malicious. So all shall be warned before implementing those. While the proposed solutions might work and be correct in aspect of C programming, that's not how you do it in audio processing. Using such things e.g. bitfields or accessing to array indexes are **highly inefficient**. Whatever you implement, check your compiled assembler code and see how much instruction you would use for all these crazy proposals. So the ones who are reading this posts again: please consider following:

**In embedded systems:**

This will be done simply by writing the byte stream to the RAM using **one simple variable to increment** (usually as assembler code) The real implementation is depending on various factors i.e. your environment.
You usually have your **samples already available** in a defined address transferred by DMA (direct memory access) feature of your CODEC if you configured it correctly.

**On a host-environment** (e.g. on windows host and doing things like VST development):

You already have the audio stream anywhere available. Depending on the stream format, it might not make sense to convert anything at all! All the CPU instructions are usually available for 32bit or 64bit words and if you convert your stream to 24bit and you will have to reconvert them to the 32bit format again one by one when processing it! (I said you, but compiler will do it. Just check your compiled code!)

Check if you have a **memory-critical** or **CPU-time-critical** system, first. If you don't have memory critical algorithms (e.g. filters, chorus, reverb, whatever) use the available stream and don't convert anything.

If you really have a memory-critical algorithm (e.g. delay, looping) and your memory ressources are limited, then you can convert the byte stream (if they are available as 4-byte-chunks) to 3-byte chunks. This will cost you instructions (CPU-time) but it's your decision. And better do it with a proper algorithm directly written as assembler code. (Copy three bytes, increment the start address 4 bytes, copy three bytes, increment the start address 4 bytes...) or similar.

Just my two cents.

Comment: *"none of the answers are very suboptimal for audio work"* means *"all of the answers are good for audio work"* which is probably not what you meant.

Answer (score -1):

Something along these lines:

```
struct Uint24
{
    unsigned char bits[3]; // assuming char is 8 bits

    Uint24()
        : bits()
    {}

    Uint24(unsigned val) {
        *this = val;
    }

    Uint24& operator=(unsigned val) {
        // store as little-endian
        bits[2] = val >> 16 & 0xff;
        bits[1] = val >> 8 & 0xff;
        bits[0] = val & 0xff;
        return *this;
    }

    unsigned as_unsigned() const {
        return bits[0] | bits[1] << 8 | bits[2] << 16;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -3):

You could do something like this;

```
union u32to24 {
    unsigned int i;
    char c[3];
};
```

in your code maniplate the values using `u32to24.i` for example

```
u32to24 val = //...

val.i += foo
val.i -= bar
// etc
```

then output the chars to get the 24 bits

```
fprintf("%c%c%c",val.c[0],val.c[1],val.c[2]);
```

**Proviso:** this is the first thing to pop into my head thus there may be errors and there may well be better ways of doing this.

Comment: This does not work; the alignment requirements will not match and your code will invoke UB.

Comment: It's a bit hacky I know. It's not guaranteed to work you're right but depending on your compiler it might well work (I've done similar things in the past) you just need to be careful when changing system/compiler

Comment: It won't work at all on modern compilers since it involves horrible violations of the aliasing rules (assuming you want to access *arrays* of samples, which is the only usage case I could imagine).

Comment: Well it works as one might expect with g++ (not sure which version but fairly up to date) and arrays work fine.

Comment: Your union is 32 bits in size, so to use an array of 24-bit values, you would have to perform pointer arithmetic to access partially-overlapping objects...