# Float to 24-bit integer in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, signal-processing

I having a Float value (32-bit)(range -1.0 to +1.0), this needs to be converted to 24-Bit value (signed data) in C for embedded application.

Could anyone let me know how can I perform this conversion?

I want something like this:

**Float   --> 24-bit integer**

-1.0    --> 0x00800000

-0.5    --> 0x00C00000

-0.25   --> 0x00E00000

0.0     --> 0x00000000

+0.25   --> 0x00200000

+0.5    --> 0x00400000

+1.0    --> 0x007FFFFF

Comment: You may want to mention which exact 24 bit format you need. 24 bit value (signed data) isn't clear to at least me.

Comment: if you want to express range (-1.0 ;1.0) you can transfer this to (0.0,2.0) and then multiply it by (2^23-1) and convert it to integer(you can round before). for converting back you divide it then subtract 1.0. Note that it will certainly lose precision.

Comment: Why do you need that? However you can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416699/how-to-define-24bit-data-type-in-c)

Comment: If you have [IEEE-754 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), and don't want to lose precision, couldn't you basically use bit masking to get the fraction field? I suspect there is some fixing to do on negative values though. (Note: I'm not expert on FP, so there might be some other issues I don't know about)

Comment: It is very strange to want **2 different scaling factors**: One scale factor -1.0 to +0.5 and another 0.5 to 1.0. It would make more sense if (1.0 - 1/pow(2,23)) --> 0x007FFFFF –

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your response.

Unfortunately I cannot use "math.h" in my development environment.

I found one of the optimized method of doing in micro-controller forum.

```
typedef union{
    struct{
        Uint16 lo;
        Uint16 hi;
    }u16;
    Uint32 u32;
    int32 i32;
    float  f;
}Versatype32;

void Float_to_I24bit(int *dest, float *src, Uint32 length)
{
register Versatype32 data;

    while(length--){
        data.f = *src;
        data.i32 = ((int32)(data.f * 8388608) & 0x00ffffff);
        *dest++ = data.u16.hi;
        *dest++ = data.u16.lo;
        src++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as multiplying the float value by `0x7FFFFF`, converting it to an integer type, and masking off the higher bits:

```
#include <math.h>

int convert(double val) {
    return lround(val * 0x7FFFFF) & 0xFFFFFF;
}
```

Note that this will map -1.0 to 0x800001 (-0x7FFFFF). Otherwise the mapping wouldn't be linear.

I chose `lround` to round the floating-point value which rounds to the nearest integer value, rounding halfway cases away from zero. Of course, you can choose any other rounding method that is available on your system and has the desired properties.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm guessing you want here is the float `f` converted to an integer in a certain unit equal to one in 2^23, because we have 23 bits of data to work with. E.g. similar to how an audio sampler would do it. I assume your floats are in the range -1 to 1, and 'ceiling' any values outside of that automatically.

```
uint32_t convert(float f) {
// Special code for NaN and infinity...
if(isnan(f) || !isfinite(f)) {
    return 0;
}

// Make sure f is in the conversion range
// Use a 'double' here to support all normal float values for f.
double t = f * 8388608.0f;
double a = abs(t);
if(a > 8388608.0f) {
    if(f > 0) {
        // f is a 'large' number (>=1.0) 
        // return the largest integer.
        return 0x007FFFFF;
    } else {
        // f is a 'large negative' number (<= -1.0)
        // return the largest negative integer
        return 0x00800000;
    }
} else {
    // Manual two's complement integer creation
    if(f >= 0) {
        return (uint32_t) a;
    } else {
        return 0x01000000 - (uint32_t) a;
    }
}
}
```

Note: You will need to add custom code to deal with the 'special' float values in the way you want (NaN, -infinity, and +infiniy).  If you are on a windows environment, you have to roll your own isfinite code instead of using the standard macro. This code will require the `<math.h>` header.

Comment: I would say 25 bits: `float` between 0.0 and 1.0 can represent exactly all multiplies of `pow(1,-24)` as [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has 24 bits of precision: 23 store explicitly and 1 implied.  Then there is the sign bit.

Comment: Do you want the `int` function `double a = abs(t);` or `double a = fabs(t); or float a = fabsf(t);`?

Answer (score -1):

OP's request is likely a little mis-stated.

```
-1.0  --> 0x00800000
-0.5  --> 0x00C00000
-0.25 --> 0x00E00000
 0.0  --> 0x00000000
+0.25 --> 0x00200000
+0.5  --> 0x00400000
+1.0  --> 0x007FFFFF ???
```

This last data point more likely should be

```
(+1.0 - pow(2,-23)) --> 0x007FFFFF
```

Assume input is `float`, output needs 24-bit int or better, so use `long` (`int` may only be 16-bit)

```
#include <math.h>

long convert(float value) {
    return (long) roundf(value * 0x800000);
}
```

---

Alternatively and non-portably, could add 3.0 to put the input in the range [2.0 to 4.0) and pull the bits out of a union.

```
uint32_ t convert2(float value) {
  union {
    uint32_t i;
    float f;
  } x;
  x.f = value + 3.0f;
  return (x.i - 0x00800000) & 0x00FFFFFF; 
}
```

Return type could be `int24_t` is you have it.  (Not so uncommon in embedded world.)