# Which C type should be used in this protocol implementation?

Tags: c, performance, protocols

There are communication protocol definitions that use fields for values that are multiple of bytes but don't use all the space in C types such as uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t and uint64_t.

For example take this fake protocol (every line is a byte):

```
*        | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
*
* 1      |     TYPE      |     spare     |
* 2      |         Packet Number         |
* 3      |         Packet Number         |
* 4      |       Number Of Packets       |
* 5      |       Number Of Packets       |
* 6      |       Number Of Packets       |
* 7      |        Number Of Octet        |
* 8      |        Number Of Octet        |
* 9      |        Number Of Octet        |
* 10     |        Number Of Octet        |
* 11     |        Number Of Octet        |
```

There are fields that can easily fit in C types such as TYPE and spare fields using uint8_t and bit operations or Packet Number in a uint16_t. But what about the fields Number Of Packets and Number Of Octet?

Questions:

- It should be used uint32_t for Number Of Packets and uint64_t for Number Of Octets even though they only use 24 bits and 40 bits respectively?
- It should be created a new type using bitfield for 24 bits and 40 bits? [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416699/how-to-define-24bit-data-type-in-c)
- Or it should be used uint8_t[3] and uint8_t[5] arrays to hold this values?

Im asking this trying to have the best time performance.

Thanks!

Comment: This is really hard to answer without context information. And even then I'm not sure if there is a "best" solution. My overall advice: keep it simple and write the code so it is portable.

Comment: @Jabberwocky There is always different ways to do the same thing so I mention some of my ideas to implement it. As I said Im searching the best time performance so maybe an answer could be: use uint32_t because its faster than trying to use only the 24 bits... I don't know. What context information do you think that I should include. Tell me and I will edit the post. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it important that the packet is as small as possible because the transmission channel (whatever this is) is slow? Or do you need the packing code (and unpacking code) to be as efficient as possible because your platform (which you didn't mention) is very slow?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I was trying to do the packing/unpacking code as efficient as possible and not exceed the maximum protocol length. If I use uint64_t for the Number Of Octet field the maximum protocol length will be exceeded, right?

Comment: You should avoid structure bitfields for serialization: [Should I use bit-fields for mapping incoming serial data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55823879/694733)

Comment: Thank you @user694733! That was one of the questions i had with bitfields :D

Comment: Nobody can say what would be fastest without knowing a lot of information missing from this question, including how frequently data will be moved into and out of the fields from and to other types of data, what machines it will be executed on, how fast the communication channel is, and more. For example, if some 24-but value will be set once and used many times without change while other fields are modified as the packet is reused, then use a 24-bit field for it. If the field will be changed many times and copying three bytes is “slow”, then maybe an aligned 32-bit field should be used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, I was only trying to simplify the question. I'm focusing on performance but only in the time the protocol is parsing the header, it has nothing to do about the communication channel. Your answer helps me see that I need to know before the times that I will be changing each field. Thanks!